# how to inspect element for xcode ui test like appium inspector

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am doing xcode ui test forl an app. Previously i used

```
appium
```

by which i can know the detail path of any element. Through its inspector, i can know the element name or xpath or anything.

But as per request, recently i switched to xcode ui test.

I am facing issue in this new technology. I can't get the element details.

It gives details through record but this does not work all time.

Sometimes it's too much long.

```
Is there any way to inspect the element like appium inspector so that
i can write my element path accordingly by myself without recording?
```

Comment: @PhillipMills The link unfortunately is broken

Answer (score 10):

There are total 3 ways to do this:

1. Accessibility Inspector from Simulator: Enable it on simulator by going to Settings->General->Accessibility->Accessibility Inspector. Then hover over an element to get the accessibility Label or Identifier.
2. Accessibility Inspector from Xcode developer tools: Right click on Xcode and open developer tool -> Accessibility Inspector.
3. debugDescription: It prints the elements of the view, you can use it in the console like:

   `XCUIApplication().debugDescription`

or better:

```
var string = XCUIApplication().debugDescription
string = Array(arrayLiteral: string).reduce("") {$0 + ($1 == "" ? "\n" : $1)}
print(string)
```

Unlike `Appium` `XCTest` is more development centric, you will find it easy to work with if you set and own the accessibility of the application. You can set `accessibilityIdentifier` to elements and consume the values in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Xcode debug view hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html)

Comment: This link no longer works (it redirects to the Xcode main page).